# Computer fan only turns on when, turning off the computer

Tags: laptop-repair

As the summary states, I know it's getting power, cause it spins, when, turning off the computer. Any ideas?
Update: swapped the fan, same thing, so, I know it's not the fan, which didn't seem to make much sense, anyway. Since like I said it still worked, but only when turning off the computer.

Comment: Try clearing the CMOS.

Comment: Is the computer overheating?  Is it a case fan, CPU, chipset ect?

Comment: The computer isn't overheating, but it does have dual fans, and it's the CPU fan.

Comment: Try running a CPU stress-test. Perhaps the fan doesn't turn on because it's not needed at low usage.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I don't that's it. I have run a stress test, of sort. It was the built in diagnostics, failed in the fan test.. and like I said, it has dual fans, the other fan kicks on at max, full speed, right from the get go, right at startup/bootup (POST..).